Elegantly tell content-assist that my "S_Something" class is really always "S<....something....>"
Problem
I have S<?,?,?,?> as a template class.
By design, a function f() always accepts a parameter of type S<?,?,?,?>*.
The below code works fine, but I lose the content-assist quality-of-life.
template<
     class Src_Param
    ,class Dst_Param
    ,int X1_Param
    ,int X2_Param
>class S{public:
    using Src=Src_Param;
    using Dst=Dst_Param;
    static constexpr int X1=X1_Param;
    static constexpr int X2=X2_Param;
};
template<class S_Something> static void f(S_Something* s){
    s->                  ///<== test 1
}

When press -> or ctrl+enter, here is the assist I get from IDE.
It is sad and empty. ::-

My poor workaround
I create a cosmetic alias named Self.
The new alias is simple.
In every use-case, Self<T> = T, and T here is always S<....something....> (by design).
template<class Param> using Self
     =S<typename Param::Src,typename Param::Dst,Param::X1,Param::X2>;  
template<class S_Something> static void f(S_Something* s){
    using S2=Self<S_Something>;
    S2* s2=s;
    s2->                 ///<== test 2
    S2::                 ///<== test 3
}

Now, I got my sweet content-assist (intellisense) back.  It works.
Here is the result from test2.

Here is the result from test3.

^^ It works and it is beautiful.
Question
Unfortunately, my new Self alias decreases the maintainability.
If I need to add more template parameters like S::X3_Param, the Self have to be updated as well.
Is there a way to hint content-assist (preferably by using proper syntax), that S_Something  inside f() is always S<...something...>, without sacrifice performance?
I am using Visual Studio, but I prefer a solution that does not depend on IDE.

The workaround is not actually equivalent to the original code. In the original code(test1) there is not way for to know what comes after s-> at the time of writing the code. The workaround(for test2 and test3) is different than what you want in test1.

"By design, a function f() always accepts" - How many such functions are there?

"By design, a function f() always accepts a parameter of type S<?,?,?,?>*..." No it doesn't. Currently f places no restriction on the parameter type. Use a concept or something else to restrict the parameter.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica :: At most 3.   Yes, I can update it manually, but the feeling that there might be some better code style keep nagging me.

@user12002570 :: Sorry, I meant to say  'it is up in my mind' or 'every real use case of the function'.  I am not sure about a good word to describe.  English is not my native language. TT

There is a better code style. If you want to only accept specializations of S then spell it out: template<class Src, class Dst, int X1, int X2> static void f(S<Src, Dst, X1, X2>*); - It's clear on what you want, to other people, the compiler, and IDE. If the parameter list changes, it's easy to track and do the refactor for a half decent IDE. And intellisense can hazard a guess about what's passed into the function. I understand some might not like it personally, but the layers of indirection built to not write straight forward code isn't elegance, it's just complexity.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica :: It is very useful.  It may be actually what I want.  Thanks a lot. (How come I forget to think about this?)

This is "old C++". It never stands out next to the shiny new meta-programming facilities.


By design, a function f() always accepts a parameter of type S*.

No, currently you haven't placed any restriction on the template parameter S_Something so at the time of writing the code there is no way to know what comes after s->.
You can solve this by changing f so that f's function parameter is of type S<S_Something>. Doing this will also give make your other test cases work.
//the template parameters can be deduced and you'll get the suggestions after s-> etc
template<class Src, class Dst, int X1, int X2> static void f(S<Src, Dst, X1, X2>*);

